# Type definitions for Elm

Tags: npm, elm, definitelytyped

TypeScript has a mechanism for providing types of libraries using [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). Is there a way to use JavaScript libraries from npm in *Elm* with some kind of type guarantees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no mechanism like DefinitelyTyped for Elm.

To use JavaScript from Elm you have a couple of choices: Elm [ports](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html) and native code, the former being the recommended mechanism.

With ports you'd essentially be using message-passing to request some functionality implemented in JavaScript.

With native code, you'd be implementing a binding between Elm and JavaScript, using both languages to do so. I suppose this is the closest thing to DefinitelyTyped. You can take a look at an existing module that uses native code, such as [Dom](https://github.com/elm-lang/dom), in order to get a sense for how to do it. Note that if you use native code, the Elm package server will generally refuse to serve your module.

Comment: The Dom package doesn't have any effect managers. Did you mean "native code"? As far as I know, Effect managers can't talk to JS anyway. It is also possible that I don't know the terminology myself!

Comment: Good question. Perhaps it is you who has the right terminology.

Comment: Yes, I believe you mean native code :) Effect managers are for implementing side effects; they allow you to expose commands and subscriptions. Some effect managers do call out to JS, but that's because they also use native code.